# Typescript failing to infer type (conditional types with extended union)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-conditional-types

I have explained the problem by comments below. It is not as complex as the size of the code block would make it seem, just trying to include an easy to follow example.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-IjqKx5EJrVBAyR6Px0AT2Il2DWpYHEJcGS2UQhyIeAly1PdzR7OAjzEC4lXxahzzoRgtF0eZAhvTNszJZg9iVAZa0nUBGEfKl8mEOQY38fCjEI6A70LJ5-2Oc5zlAF9rCRCoPzVGB9B-Dsd0A4DLDAiDBwvcj0EowD4P3JC+2PKJhF4jCz0UygKOqOJvCccgqFoOh80LZhaIcfICGIcyynuR5rLVAYYCMJiK3eWM-wA1ygx6RM6mEdBzn0AAaYwgwi8prQMdAZFEdB9CA2AQLkqlIN2AyjLiOC1SUWxBkGBDcg0lCtDmaBfh4849PPMjDOU4yqMc5wLPoNiOJIuzeAcsyXCMQNQF64j0U8hcuPQXyg1GAKpKCx0Kk-FKIui2KtEVCobX0ZLUvSmTQPAnKFJagq0iK9EStAMqKoPZD+30SgvmJeEmuw3CAlY9N2Mm9BSKUlTTKc256BYAbQHyZZBPeFprHqHSaCXNGnzAHDmIMP7b0BmKlWo-jNzfYT7q1Kc0gmTFQxxOiwDBCsIyJYh3m61boBimoowHN5sUqULidfLotHmxKDpSwVxMeBMALO+ywHgZTVpEaAZARuAlgiygwXucNFSAsFqngJR5Kg-K2sKz87oezIgA)

**Bottomline question: Why does the type inference fail at the end?**

```js
// Fancy type
type ItemErrors<IT> = {
  [P in keyof IT]?: IT[P] extends object ? 
    ItemErrors<IT[P]> 
  : IT[P] extends any[] ? 
    string[] 
  : string
};

// Purpose of the fancy type is to be the same "shape" as given type but to represent (optional) errors for its properties

// Say there are two types that both have a name property

type WithName = {
    name: string
    other: number
    obj: {
        inner: boolean
    }
}

type AlsoWithName = {
    name: string
    cool: boolean
}

// A union of those two types can only say for certain that it has a name

type UnionHasName = WithName | AlsoWithName

// this thing requires a string

function prints(mustbestring: string){
    console.log(mustbestring)
}

function works(my: UnionHasName){
    // must have a name and that is a string. check.
    prints(my.name)
}

function alsoWorks<T extends UnionHasName>(something: T){
    // if it extends UnionHasName it still must have a name and that a string. check.
    prints(something.name)
}

function stillWorks(something: ItemErrors<WithName>){
    // ItemErros for WithName means it either has a string for the name field, or else undefined. check.
    prints(something.name ?? "")
}

function evenStillWorks(something: ItemErrors<UnionHasName>){
    // ItemErros for UnionHasName means it either has a string for the name field, or else undefined. check.
    prints(something.name ?? "")
}

function doesNotWork<T extends UnionHasName>(something: ItemErrors<T>){
    // but here it fails...
    // T extends UnionHasName, so T must have a "name: string" property
    // within itemerrors then, that property of name must be either undefined or a string.
    // yet the inference below fails. why?
    prints(something.name ?? "")
}
```

Comment: TS does not do well with inferring when there are both generics and conditionals are involved. Because you're trying to infer `T` from an object that is based on `ItemErrors`, it cannot be sure what's going on. The result being that `something.name` is of type `string | ItemErrors<T["name"]> | string[] | undefined`.

Comment: Conditionals can **block** inference of generic parameters if it is "too complex".

Comment: That is an interesting statement @kelsny - do you have a source you could point me to and/or any further explanation about why that would be the case here?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. It's just something I have noticed with my usage of TypeScript. The compiler seems to "give up" when it can't evaluate a complex conditional and defers it. In this case it deferred the evaluation so it can't see that the type of `name` is `string | undefined`. At least that's just my theory :>

Comment: @kelsny - thanks. fair enough. that certainly does seem to be what is happening. and while I recognize such cases would exist (even just for performance optimization in absence of any true logical limit) I was surprised to find this case here where a human can follow logical steps to inference so easily to be one of those scenarios.

Comment: if either of you at least think this is a fair / good question I would appreciate the upvote to try for it to get more attention

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue seems that TS currently won't take into account given generic constraints when evaluating conditional types for the sake of inference.

In my specific case, I realized the requirement represented by the generic constraint was actually tightly coupled (always true) for places where I wanted to use the conditional type, so I just "duplicated" the constraint into the conditional type logic and that seems to work.

[Updated Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEEMDsGME9QBd4AcCmAoFHQEkl0BbAUQCcyB7MgZwB48AVAPlAF5QBvTUUAbQAKoAJbRQAa3TxKAM3yMAugH4AXPMELQ6AB6FoAExqhKAIwBW6WElBLQPXvkKkK1ekw2t7a9wM069hqAw8Hyatva8NEhkogDmoXa8alEx0LGYAL4A3JiYIKACAK5kqJQ06MZySAAWFTIwCMhoFcJGSJSgJhU1FTSQRBUARDTVkBiDQUaxwgBu6GI4FSaF1u2gZOioG+XQ1gAUlKhIwpTQkAA2AJRaLrSgMtQiSEZbh+hkx+g0ufkAypCIHobILApAAdw6izao2sJkoNVAozmQVAZwGoFeGA+8Fyi1AAHVhDUAHL9CocbgOVFk5LROIRYxAtTQQpELpkBmmMxqSlUhyiaDvNRwyjndAwBkZTK45qgACC5xolEJJLJ7C4DLR6FpqXSVNglFFwsNYolUryYDloEK0BOYlkyGqZW6EKaGCMsBgxmg50QfUQDzIoFg7yQkFEjsg1iJiMgRkg1IGMtwAFVbacABJx0nojgq6o5ioAH3liuVRILZJ+YBqrUdcXW6AAjoVhNsUSl6ZgZDarHaMalnnsiIUol1O2kdXFLrzeAboEqxQA6c6UWLD0dIcd0tKXaXd3vHU6gCFkcQ0YfwNRpu1ZmiFmcM-IjqKx5EJrVBAyR6Px0AT2Il2DWpYHEJcGS2UQhyIeAly1PdzR7OAjzEC4lXxahzzoRgtF0eZAhvTNszJZg9iVAZa0nUBGEfKl8mEOQY38fCjEI6A70LJ5-2Oc5zlAF9rCRCoPzVGB9B-Dsd0A4DLDAiDBwvcj0EowD4P3JC+2PKJhF4jCz0UygKOqOJvCccgqFoOh80LZhaIcfICGIcyynuR5rLVAYYCMJiK3eWM-wA1ygx6RM6mEdBzn0AAaYwgwi8prQMdAZFEdB9CA2AQLkqlIN2AyjLiOC1SUWxBkGBDcg0lCtDmaBfh4849PPMjDOU4yqMc5wLPoNiOJIuzeAcsyXCMQNQF64j0U8hcuPQXyg1GAKpKCx0Kk-FKIui2KtEVCobX0ZLUvSmTQPAnKFJagq0iK9EStAMqKoPZD+30SgvmJeEmuw3CAlY9N2Mm9BSKUlTTKc256BYAbQHyZZBPeFprHqHSaCXNGnzAHDmIMP7b0BmKlWo-jNzfYT7q1Kc0gmTFQxxOiwDBCsIyJYh3m61boBimoowHN5sUqULidfLotHmxKDpSwVxMeBMALO+ywHgZTVpEaAZARuAlgiygwXucNFSAsFqngJR5Kg-K2sKz87oe-dsFlPAiFeOZ9E65zLKYVgKXsQRVYkKQHSYZRvCxvCcfG-6+tuxIHD2Hw-DDwIuUsaxwj5Bw3YhhhGA8GOknUXwfpYr8QjCPO+QAhIGUp2Jri8RLxGgHXoEyHIns0sRhCdqgXaayGi-Dib7xIy7LY67vKBdzPuuw2zZwHc3R5Um6Kht8rMiAA)

```js
type ImprovedItemErrors<IT> = {
  [P in keyof IT]?: IT extends UnionHasName ? 
    (IT[P] extends object ? 
        ItemErrors<IT[P]> 
    : IT[P] extends any[] ? 
        string[] 
    : string) 
  : unknown
};

function improvedWorks<T extends UnionHasName>(something: ImprovedItemErrors<T>){
    prints(something.name ?? "")
}
```